# i can't solve an error ''type '' is not a subtype of type ''''

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to pass the index to the next screen with this.
How do i pass the index to brand.dop and not brand?

```
     onTap: () {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => (Model(brand: brand.dop[index],))),
      );
    },
```

but i have an error

***type 'Acura' is not a subtype of type 'Brand'***
Also I tried use `brand: brands[index]` this returns the wrong index
Datafile's structure

Brand:

```
  Brand(
    id: 1,
    title: "ACURA",
    image: "images/acura-logo.png",
    dop: acuras,
  ),
```

Acura:

```
  Acura(
    subject_id: 100,
    subject_title: "ILX",
    subject_image: "images/acura/ilx.png",
    model: ilxmodels,
  ),
```

ilxmodel:

```
  Ilxmodel(
      model_id: 10000,
      model_title: "ILX",
      model_image: "images/acura/ilx.png",
      kmh: 1
  ),
```

Thanks

Comment: kindly share some more code from the page you're using this brand model.

Comment: `child: Image.asset(
                              brand.dop[index].model[index].model_image,
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            ),`

Comment: I use brand: brand[index] to returns dop List with brand index, but when i want use brand.dop index for model List it's return an error. Also if it important, each list have individual page. first page - brand. second page - brand.dop. thrird page - brand.dop.model. for example on second page i use `brand.dop[index].subject_title`

Comment: `Brand.dop` is a `List<Acura>` if I understand your code samples. If so, you're trying to assign an `Acura` instance to  `Model.brand`, which clearly won't work. Perhaps you should consider making `Acura` a subclass of `Brand` (i.e. `class Acura extends Brand`)`

Comment: I'm so inconsiderate. Thanks, you solved my problem

Comment: I can't seem to mark your answer as a helpful answer. Don't know how do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, it seems as `Brand.dop` is a list of `Acura` instances, i.e. `List<Acura>`.

This means you're trying to assign an `Acura` instance to `Model.brand`, which clearly won't work. Probably `Model.brand` is of the type `Brand`, not `Acura`.

One solution could be to make `Acura` a subclass of `Brand`:

```
class Acura extends Brand
```